# Formally describing a sensor network language

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages, semantics

I have a language for sensor networks (generates C code) and I want to define the formal semantics of it.

The language has this form:

```
{STATE name_state:
EVERY time
SELECT {variable [, variable] ...}
[SENDIF send_condition]
[CHANGEIF change_condition GOTO new_state];
} ...

START IN initial_state;
```

- The initial state of the program is specified by the START IN instruction.
- Each state is defined by the STATE instruction.
- In the specification of each state the clauses EVERY and SELECT are compulsory and the clauses SENDIF and CHANGEIF are optional.
- The CHANGEIF clause is only not specified when there is a single state.

What type of formal semantics is more convenient to use?

Comment: Are you after the formal semantics or a more formal way of describing the syntax? It sounds like the latter.

Comment: See his comment to my answer, looks like he's interested in both.

Comment: [Yuval Filmus](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus), [Dave Clarke](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/31/dave-clarke) I will  describe the sintax using the Backus-Naur form and edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of timed automaton model.

Comment: If I use a timed automata model I have to represent using a concrete example. Is this correct?

Comment: @DaveClarke I think that a variant of a PLC-automata is a good way to specify the language. 
Changes: More than one output. Addition of a condition assessment for the outputs. Transitions based on conditions.

What do you think about this form of specification?.

Comment: Sounds suitable, from what information I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, axiomatic semantics is the nicest form of semantics, but is difficult to obtain for anything but the most simple languages, and subject of much current research. Denotational semantics is a vague term, if you mean domain theoretic semantics, then I advise against it. In general using operational semantics is easy and natural, especially if you use state-based SOS (structural operational semantics). The fact that you already have a translation into C is a strong indication that this would work in your case, because C can be seen as a state-based formalism.

Indeed your translation into C is a formal semantics of your sensor network language, albeit a painfully detailed one. So I guess you want a formal description that isto omit some level of detail (e.g. integers are 'real' mathematical integers and not some kind of finite modulo arithmetic). For this state-based SOS tends to be ideal.

Comment: You think I should work in the specified sensor network language? or feel that I have to work more at the generated code in C?.

Comment: @ClaudioBiale it depends on you and what you are trying to achieve. If you want to communicate with other people, then using C might not be helpful since few people voluntarily read code. A more abstract, less detailed presentation could be easier to understand. If you are just trying to clarify matters for yourself, writing an additional semantic account to accompany C code could be overkill. So there's no one answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to formalize the semantics of the sensor network language. I'll look previous work using structured operational semantics and try to apply it in this language.

Comment: @ClaudioBiale That sounds like a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

[Backus-Naur form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) used to be popular for these purposes. Another possibility is [Wirth syntax notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth_syntax_notation). You can find other possibilities in the "see also" section of the article on Backus-Naur form.

Comment: Using the Backus-Naur form I describe the sintax of the language, but what type of approaches it is convenient to use to providing a formal semantics of this type of programming language (denotational, axiomatic or operational).